# Gradient checking implementation in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement gradient checking in Java (currently used with linear regression), but it doesn't seem to work.  I tested my linear regression code alongside python linear regression with the same set of data and got the same gradients and line of best fit. I want to check if my implementation of gradient checking is correct, to isolate where the error could be. I can't post my entire code because the last time I did that I was discouraged from it, so I will just post a snippet of my method and please operate under the assumption that all methods work as intended.

As suggested by a commenter, I now ran a test case to find actual vs predicted values. When running gradient check using x values of 1, 2, 3 and y values of 2, 3, 4 I got -2.84 as the approximate gradient for the first weight (theta0 which would be b in ax + b). The result I got from linear regression was -9, which is significantly different. However I am more inclined to believe the linear regression is corrected as linear regression performs fine on the data, but using the approximated values that gradient checking comes up with gives an inaccurate result. While debugging my code I found no errors in the methods used, so I am inclined to believe that it is an error with my algorithm

- `euclidianDistance` subtracts two vectors, squares each value in the new vector, sums the values, and then takes the square root of that.
- `euclidianLength` squares each value in the vector, sums them, and then takes the square root.
- `setElement` sets the element of a matrix to the specified element at the specified row and column index. I have tried epsilon values of 10^-4 and 10^-7 which still didn't work.

```
public double gradientCheck(double epsilon){
double[][] dApprox = new double[this.weights.getHeight()][this.weights.getWidth()];
//create a cost vector which has each theta have +epsilon and the cost divided by 2*epsilon
for (int row = 0; row < this.weights.height; row++) {
  Matrix tempWeight = this.weights;
  //sets the theta value to itself + epsilon
  tempWeight.setElement(this.weights.getElement(row, 0) + epsilon, row, 0);
  Matrix hyp = trainInputs.multiplyMatrix(tempWeight);
  Matrix err = hyp.subtractMatrix(trainOutputs);
  //compute the cost of this new vector
  double val = cost(err);

  //do the same thing but with theta-epsilon
  tempWeight = this.weights;
  //sets the theta value to itself + epsilon
  tempWeight.setElement(this.weights.getElement(row, 0) - epsilon, row, 0);
  hyp = trainInputs.multiplyMatrix(tempWeight);
  err = hyp.subtractMatrix(trainOutputs);
  //compute the cost of this new vector
  double newVal = cost(err);

  double finalVal = (val - newVal) / (2.0 * epsilon);
  //vector which has the final dApprox
  dApprox[row][0] = finalVal;
}
Matrix approx = new Matrix(dApprox);
double numerator = Matrix.euclideanDistance(approx, dTheta);
double denominator = Matrix.euclideanLength(approx.addMatrix(dTheta));

return (numerator / denominator);
}
```

A few more notes:

`dApprox` is what I am calling my approximated gradient values and `dTheta` is the real gradient values. The results I am getting are in the 0.9 - 1 range which wouldn't make sense given the supposed accuracy of my linear regression algorithm.

- `trainInputs` is a matrix of the training data with a column of 1s attached before it.
  -`trainOutputs` is simply the outputs as a m*1 matrix where m is the number of datapoints (in this case it is simply [[2], [3], [4]]

If there is nothing conceptually wrong with the algorithm please let me know, that way I can make sure the problem is within one of the methods and not with the actual implementation.

Comment: What are `trainInputs` and `trainOutputs` - function arguments? What data type?

Comment: And you need not post whole code, but at least proper function signature with arguments and return values, sample inputs to the function arguments, sample expected output and actual output. That should be okay for a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I took some time to go through a sample case and come up with an actual vs expected value that I am now updating the post with.

Comment: You should try printing the values of the matrices and compare it with the results you get on paper. Maybe you will find some issue with your algorithm.

Comment: I tried doing the whole thing on paper and actually got the same result as the code. I am pretty certain at this point it is something wrong with my algorithm, although I am not sure what because the resources I used seemed to do a similar thing. The matrix values I am getting are identical to me doing it on paper.